# The term 'mvn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet in gitlab ci cd pipeline yaml file

Tags: maven, build, gitlab, pipeline, cicd

trying build maven project using gitlab specific runner getting error
My .gitlab-ci.yml content

```
variables:
    MAVEN_OPTS: -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository

image: maven:latest

stages:
    - build
    - test
    - package
    - deploy


cache:
    paths:
        - .m2/repository
        - target
build_job:
    stage: build
    tags:
        - docker
    
    script:
        - echo "Maven compile started"
        - "mvn compile"

test_job:
    stage: test
    tags:
        - docker

    script:
        - echo "Maven test started"
        - "mvn test"

package_job:
    stage: package
    tags:
        - docker

    script:
        - echo "Maven packaging started"
        - "mvn package"

Deploy_job:
    stage: deploy
    tags:
        - docker

    script:
        - echo "Maven deploy started"


error : $ mvn compile
mvn : The term 'mvn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\build_script1691068991\script.ps1:243 char:1
+ mvn compile
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mvn:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Your Gitlab configuration is broken.
Note the stack trace that shows that the command was executed on Windows maschine, instead in Docker container. 
Remove the runners that are inapt of running Docker correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using docker specific runner and set environment in your config.tomal file. My docker specific runner config is below.

[[runners]]
  name = "Docker-runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  id = *******
  token = "****************"
  token_obtained_at = ***********
  token_expires_at = **********
  executor = "docker"
  environment = ["MAVEN_HOME=C:/Softwares/Maven/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin"]
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).